# What is the meaning of 'len()-i-1' and why we use this to get last index value. (i=0)

Tags: python, indexing

Am checking palindrome words. My code is mentioned below

```
num='1,2,3,4,5'

for i in range(0,len(num)):

  if num(i)==num[len(num)-i-1]:
```

Here i got confused. What is the meaning of len()-i-1. I know that len() will get the length of the value and minus 1 will get total length-1 value. But leng()-1-1 why we using and how it working?

Answer (score 1):

You that because accessing arrays, string are 0-indexed, so

Example for `12321`, it's `len` is `5`

```
range i   0 1 2 3 4
len-i     5 4 3 2 1  <- index error at first
len-i-1   4 3 2 1 0  <- opposite of first row : OK
```